# Creating a counting column query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to create a select query that will have a column that counts the number of times someone has been trained in a certain month. I have managed to get it to show the list of people who went to training sessions in that specific month, but I want to show everyone else as well with a 0 count of the sessions they attended. How would I do this?

```
SELECT 
    carer.carer_firstname, carer.carer_lastname,   
    COUNT(carer_training_link.carer_id) AS sessions_attended_May
FROM 
    carer, carer_training_link 
WHERE 
    carer.carer_id = carer_training_link.carer_id 
    AND carer_training_link.training_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/MAY/2019', 'DD/MON/YYYY') 
                                              AND TO_DATE('01/JUN/2019', 'DD/MON/YYYY')
GROUP BY 
    carer.carer_firstname, carer.carer_lastname;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Another bad habit to kick: using the table name as a redundant prefix of the column names.  And another bad habit to kick: Asking for help with a query without providing the table definitions, assuming people can figure it out based on the query code.  See [minimal reproducible exampl](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: @EdStevens I'll take the advice on, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a join sytax that can only be called antique.

You want an outer join, so as to include carers that had no training.

Date ranges are best compared with `>=` and `<`.

```
SELECT 
  c.carer_firstname, c.carer_lastname,   
  COUNT(cl.carer_id) AS sessions_attended_may
FROM carer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN carer_training_link cl
  ON cl.carer_id  = c.carer_id
  AND cl.training_date >= DATE '2019-05-01'
  AND cl.training_date <  DATE '2019-06-01'
GROUP BY c.carer_firstname, c.carer_lastname
ORDER BY c.carer_firstname, c.carer_lastname;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to note the newer join methods